# Как убрать уникальность индекса в Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Столкнулся с проблемой в Identity. Для авторизации использую OpenIddict. В стандартном IdentityUser поле NormalizedUserName уникально:

```
b.HasIndex("NormalizedUserName")
    .IsUnique()
    .HasName("UserNameIndex")
    .HasFilter("[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать уникальность с этого поля? (используя Fluent API или еще как-то, учитывая то, что нужное поле находится в классе библиотеки).
У меня в проекте уникальность пользователя проверяется по дополнительному параметру (несколько подсайтов, пользователь может зарегистрироваться на каждом из них без пересечения с остальными).

Пробовал так, не помогло:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<PanelUser>()
        .HasIndex(u => u.NormalizedUserName)
        .HasName("UserNameIndex")
        .HasFilter("[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

Если ручками убрать Unique в классе миграции - все работает как мне надо. Но каждый раз переписывать миграцию не очень удобно.

Comment: Создать свой класс пользователя, отнаследоваться, переопределить всё, что не нравится. Один раз сгенерировать миграцию, применить и забыть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто переопределить нужное поле не помогло. Нужно было в OnModelCreating явно указать **IsUnique(false)**, чтобы переписать конфигурацию из недр библиотек:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<PanelUser>()
        .HasIndex(u => u.NormalizedUserName)
        .HasName("UserNameIndex")
        .HasFilter("[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL")
        .IsUnique(false);
}
```

Помимо этого расположил **base.OnModelCreating(builder)** в начале метода. Без этого часть настроек не переопределялась.